# Tmux, cron doesn't work with my python script on google clouds

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, cron, tmux

so i am trying to run my python script 24/7 using google cloud machine, I want to use tmux and cron but i think i am doing something wrong and it doesn't work for me. When i run my script in SSH window it works perfectly but when i close it. It doesn't post to twitter or edit my json file.

I tried looking for answer in google but no luck for me.
I have tried using tmux and running my script with infinite loop and no lock.
I have tried using cron without infinite loop and run my script every 5 minutes and no luck.
I have tried using cron inside tmux and no luck.

```py
import requests
import json
import time
import twitter

class TodayILearned():
    def __init__(self):
        self.link = 'https://www.reddit.com/r/todayilearned/new/.json'

    def get_info(self):
        try:
            r = requests.get(self.link, headers = {'User-agent': 'your bot 0.1'})
            r.raise_for_status()
        except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as error:
            print(f'There is problem:\n{error}')
            return False
        new_til = json.loads(r.content)
        new_til = new_til["data"]["children"][0]['data']['title']
        new_til = new_til.replace('TIL', '').replace('Til', '').strip()
        for _ in range(len(new_til) - 1):
            if new_til[0].isalpha() == False:
                new_til = new_til.replace(new_til[0], '').strip()#.capitalize()
            else:
                break
        new_til = new_til.split(' ', 1)
        if new_til[0].lower() == 'this' or new_til[0].lower() == 'that' or new_til[0].lower() == 'about' or new_til[0].lower() == 'of':
            new_til.pop(0)
        new_til = ' '.join(new_til)
        new_til = new_til[:1].upper() + new_til[1:]
        if new_til[-1].isalnum() == True:
            new_til += '.'
        return new_til if len(new_til) < 280 else False #change for 140 when twitter working 

    def save_new_dict(self, new_dict):
        with open('til_news_base.json', 'w') as json_file:
            json.dump(new_dict, json_file, indent=2)

    def read_json_file(self):
        with open('til_news_base.json') as json_file:
            data = json.load(json_file)
        self.last_key = int(sorted(list(data.keys()))[-1])
        return data

    def post_on_twitter(self, new_post):
        TOKEN = 'xxx'
        TOKEN_KEY = 'xxx'
        CON_SEC = 'xxx'
        CON_SEC_KEY = 'xx'
        my_auth = twitter.OAuth(TOKEN,TOKEN_KEY,CON_SEC,CON_SEC_KEY)
        twit = twitter.Twitter(auth=my_auth)
        twit.statuses.update(status=new_post)

    def program(self):
        wait_for_seconds = 30
        while True:
            #first load the base from file
            dict_with_news = self.read_json_file()
            #second get new posts from reddit
            new_info = self.get_info()
            #check if new post in base or if is it last post
            if new_info != False:
                if new_info != dict_with_news[str(self.last_key)]:
                    dict_with_news[str(self.last_key + 1)] = new_info
                    print(new_info)
            #add to base if not
                    self.save_new_dict(dict_with_news)
            #print new TIL on twitter
                    self.post_on_twitter(new_info)
            #wait Xs
            time.sleep(wait_for_seconds)


def program():
    class_til = TodayILearned()
    class_til.program()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    program()
```

I want it to run every 5 minutes but no luck, it doesn't post new stuff to twitter after i close SSH. 
after opening my SSH connection to google cloud i write:
tmux, change directory to place where my python file and json file is. i run my python script using python3. I can see in console my new news and i can see it on twitter. I am waiting for 5 minutes and every time new stuff is posted on reddit i can see it in my console and posted on twitter. I close my SSH and there are no new posts on twitter or in json file. I open SSH again and there are no errors or anything. I tried also cron: i used command '*/5 * * * * python 3 /python_programs/watch_for_new_TIL_facts.py'
without '' of course. and still no luck.
I tried this command in cron in tmux and without it. I have created stuff as normal user and as root.

Comment: could you post how are you setting up the cron job?

Comment: '*/5 * * * * python 3 /python_programs/watch_for_new_TIL_facts.py'

Comment: but i also tried with // in file directory

Comment: I suggest you to implement some logging and try statements almost everywhere to catch de error. Or instead of putting the from job, first let the app run on a screen environment to save in stdout any error

Comment: i have run it on my own PC for 12h and i had 0 errors, i have run it on google clouds for X hours and i had no problem, there is only problem with tmux and cron. After i close my SSH connection my program thing stops working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your crontab, you have a space between `Python` and `3`. Eliminate it.